# segmentation fault with printf on linux

Tags: c, printf

@Team,

While trying to print an integer value through printf i accidentally wrote the statement as

```
int x =10;
printf(x);
```

In linux i am getting a segmentation fault when tried to execute it.
Although its wrong but can some one please help me to know the reason for it.

Strace says:

```
mprotect(0x7f872fb26000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f872fb0b000, 99154)           = 0
--- SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) @ 0 (0) ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++
```

Tried searching in SO but to no success.

Comment: And where's your format string, mister? Huh?

Comment: In `printf` function value of `x` will be interpreted as address of some string, and printf function try to access continue memories untill memory with zero found (as string terminate with `0`) -- Undefined behaviour -- One some system you may also get bus error a your are access invalid address

Comment: **Note**: as OS detects memory right violation by a process -- An invalid access to valid memory gives: `SIGSEGV` And access to an invalid address gives: `SIGBUS`). In worth case your program may execute without any failure it produces garbage results. -- your address is invalid so for some execution you may also get a SIGBUS signal

Comment: Surprised to see a down vote... any specific reasons???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting a segmentation fault because `printf` is interpreting the 10 you passed it as a `char *`, and trying to read from machine address 10. On systems that run Linux, that address is not valid and causes a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 4):

First parameter for `printf()` is format string which is `char *` pointer. So when you do `printf(x)` it takes `x` as `char *` and tries to access string stored at address `10`. But its invalid so it gives segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1):

Use printf() in proper format. printf("%d",x).